# How should I be communicating asynchronously between models and controllers in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

I have an `Authenticator` class which has a method to authenticate with an API key and another method to authenticate with an email address and password. Authentication is done with an async HTTP request.

I have a `LoginController` that is managing the view that the user will enter their email/password into.

Here's a code snippet:

```
// LoginController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
   self.authenticator = [[Authenticator alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)authenticateWithEmailAndPassword: (id)sender {
    // Async HTTP request, so we can't just check the return 
    // value to see if authentication was successful or not
    [self.authenticator authenticateWithEmail:[emailField stringValue]
                                     password:[passwordField stringValue]];
}
```

My `Authenticator` object does the authentication, and my `LoginController` needs the asynchronous result (success or failure).

What's the Objective C way of communicating asynchronously from the model back to the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible pattern you could use here would be a delegate.

You could define a `AuthenticatorDelegate` protocol and have your `LoginController` conform to it. Something like:

```
@protocol AuthenticatorDelegate
- (void) authenticationSuccessful;
- (void) authenticationFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
@end

@interface Authenticator : NSObject
{
    ...
    id <AuthenticatorDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (assign) id <AuthenticatorDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

your `LoginController` would be declared as

```
@interface LoginController : UIViewController <AuthenticatorDelegate>
...
```

and when you initialize it you set the delegate

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.authenticator = [[Authenticator alloc] init];
    self.authenticator.delegate = self;
}
```

and then when your `Authenticator` objects receive the result you just call the appropriate method on the delegate.

Of course that's just one of the possibilities. Other approaches could use code blocks or a target/selector pair.

Comment: that is how to do it. I usually write a formal protocol like above, but isn't necessary if you are only using those two classes.

Comment: @nfm: An [informal protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF147) might be sufficient in this case, just as another option. That is how `NSURLConnectionDelegate` works, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

make authenticator the delegate of the your NSURLConnection, then override the

```
connectionDidFinishLoading:
```

and

```
connection:didFailWithError:
```

save a ref to `LoginController` in the authenticator, then when you get `connectionDidFinishLoading:` you evaluate the response and send the message back to 
    `LoginController`.